# ES query over different types and join over a common field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to investigate if this is a possiblity in elasticsearch, since I want to decouple at its best the data, I would like to have inside an `index` different `types` one for each field.

**Question1**: how bad is this decision?

Now, if I've type `name`:

```
/myindex/name

{
    "name" : "mat",
    "id":1
}
```

and `surname`

```
/myindex/surname    
{
    "surname" : "txt",
    "id":1
}
```

**question 2**: how can i create a search that is `name='mat AND surname='txt'` and returns `id`?

If I run the query as this (on the index, without specifying the type):

```
/myindex/_search
{

    "query" : {
       "bool" : {
        "should" : [{
            "term" : { "name" : "mat" }
        },
        {
            "term" : { "surname" : "txt" }
        }]
       }
    }
}
```

it returns (obviusly) two documents, can I say something like `join by id` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use ElasticSearch (or any other noSQL database), you really need to change your mindset around "joins".  We don't do joins in noSQL...at all...ever.  Instead, what you should do is put duplicate data in each record.

Take the following example: Let's say I have a product, and each product has a product type.

In SQL, the 2 records would look like this:

```
| Product ID | Product Name | Product Type ID |
| ---------- | ------------ | --------------- |
| 1 | product name 1 | 99 |
| 2 | product name 2 | 99 |
```

In elasticsearch, we would store the data like this:

```
products/product/1
{
    "name": "product name 1",
    "type: {
        "type name": "product type 99"
    }
}

products/product/2
{
    "name": "product name 2",
    "type: {
        "type name": "product type 99"
    }
}
```

Notice how the product type information is duplicated in both rows.  As a general rule, noSQL has the advantage of being much faster, at the cost of data duplication.  This means that it's much harder to change the name "product type 99" because I'd need to change it in N records.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: i know this, but i would like to decouple the infos for security reasons and join them while searching. probably, what i'm trying to achieve is not yet contemplated by the implementation of ES (i'm borderline with my goal)